# Reading a csv file not working in meteor

Tags: meteor

In my meteor app I need to import csv file and read a particular coloumn of each item.
My code is

```
var fs = Npm.require('fs');
         chroot = Meteor.chroot || 'uploads';
         var path = chroot + (path ? '/' + path + '/' : '/');
         var content = fs.readFileSync('../../../../../' + path + file_name, "utf-8", function read(err, data) {
          if (err) {
             throw err;
            }

       });
```

By this I get what I want.But for some case, the csv file is like

```
name,email,phone,designation,userid
name1,name@gmail.com,manager,LI-501
name2,name2@gmail.com,"HR,Senior manager",LI-502
```

I need to retreive the user id from each coloumn ie the 3rd item.
But for the second entry there comes an extra comma for the designation and so the coloumn number changes.So which is the perfect way for reading a csv file ?

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to reinvent the wheel, there are already CSV parsers done for node.js. [This one](https://www.npmjs.org/package/csv) looks to be the most reliable. And in case you haven't done this yet, you can use [npm Meteor package](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/npm) to use npm packages within Meteor.

Comment: but when I install csv parser Im getting the error "Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets <!DOCTYPE html> for you)"

Comment: How do you install it? Inside `packages.json`, or do you do something more?

Comment: I just run npm install csv

Comment: Then you've created `npm_modules` directory, which was picked up by Meteor and is causing problems with client code (and server code probably as well). Remove that folder and its contents, add `npm` package via `mrt add npm`, and then set up `packages.json` file as described [in this documentation](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/npm).

Answer (score 0):

I used Ink filepicker's read method on an HTML input element to return the contents of the CSV file:

https://developers.inkfilepicker.com/docs/web/#read

Then I passed the contents into the jQuery CSV parser's toObjects method, which someone made into a package here:

https://atmospherejs.com/package/jquery-csv

This got me the CSV contents into a JS object which then I can manipulate as needed. There is also a toArray method in the jQuery CSV parser.

You don't have to use Ink filepicker to get the contents of the file, but it was a nice option for me since I was already using it.